Customize validation error message in BadRequest response
In my ASP.Net Core service, I have actions like the following:
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class SomethingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("something")]
    public IActionResult GetSomething([FromHeader] MyId myId)
    {
        var result = somethingProvider.GetSomething(myId);
        return Ok(result);
    }
        
    // additional actions following the same pattern
}

In addition, I have the following classes MyId, a type converter MyIdTypeConverter and a static helper class MyIdHelper:
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyIdTypeConverter))]
public class MyId
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}

public class MyIdTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string stringValue)
        {
            return MyIdHelper.Parse(stringValue);
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}

public class MyIdHelper
{
    public static MyId Parse(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The MyId string must not be null or empty!");
        }
    
        try
        {
            // do some parsing and return a MyId instance...
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new FormatException("The provided MyId string does not match the required format: x-y-z");
        }
    }
}

As you can see, I throw different kinds of exceptions with different messages in the parsing method. However, when providing invalid inputs in my request header, I only get the following validation error in the HTTP 400 response:
{
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "The value 'whatever' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Please refer to the errors property for additional details.",
    "instance": "/api/something/"
}

Instead of the generic message "The value 'whatever' is not valid.", I would like to see the message of the exception that was thrown in my TypeConverter. Is there any way to achieve this?

I would look at FluentValidation to get more granularity in regards to messages as you can return a message on a per rule basis.

@WimOmbelets Mmmh, ok, but how would I get to the validation if the conversion from string to MyId already fails?

You would validate before you parse. The output of a parse call would be the parsed MyId but before you get there you'd want to get any failures so you can forward that to the api response.

TypeConverter throws an exception, it typically doesn't directly affect the model validation process in ASP.NET Core. This happens because the model binding process doesn't propagate exceptions from the TypeConverter into the validation system in a meaningful way.
The most basic approach for handling invalid ModelState is through thin Action Filter:
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // Access a value from the request headers
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("MyId", out var headerValues))
        {
            var myIdString = headerValues.ToString();  // Get the value of the header
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myIdString))
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("The MyId string must not be null or empty!");
            }
            try
            {
                // do some parsing and return a MyId instance...
                var parts = myIdString.Split('-');
                var myId= new MyId
                {
                    X = parts[0],
                    Y = parts[1],
                    Z = parts[2]
                };
                context.ActionArguments["myId"] = myId;
            }
            catch 
            {

                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("The provided MyId string does not match the required format: x-y-z");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle missing header case
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("MyId header is missing.");
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // This method runs after the action is executed
    }
}

Register the filter:
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilter());  // Apply the filter globally
});

